# Why Bigbluebutton Recorded Session takes several hours to appear in Moodle

Tags: session, recording, bigbluebutton

I am working with Bigbluebutton configuration with Moodle through API. Everything is Working perfectly but after the Meeting is over, recorded sessions takes several hours sometimes it takes almost 24 hours to appear in the playback session. My question is, why this takes so many hours to appear in the Playback as it should appear immediately after the meeting is over. Is there any way to make it appear immediately after meeting. Any help would be appreciable.

Answer (score 1):

We see that you've posted this same question to multiple forums.  We've already responded to your question here

https://groups.google.com/d/msg/bigbluebutton-dev/6iE622xnyHk/zhF_OZunAwAJ